# Entity Framework exception for missing foreign key object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have a Web API with Entity Framework, using DB first approach.
I have 2 tables that one references the other with a Foreign Key.

```
Table A:
AID (PK)
Name

Table B:
BID (PK)
AID (FK) NOT NULL
```

I ran the `Scaffold-DbContext` command to generate the `DbContext` and the `classes`, and it looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.A)
        .WithMany(p => p.B)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.AID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_B_A");
});

class A
{
    public int AID;
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public int BID;
    public virtual A A { get; set; } = null!
}
```

When I call the API, I expect to send this `POST` request to insert new record to `B`:

```
{
  "aId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
```

When I send the request, I'm getting this error message before it even gets to the break point in code:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-ecaa066f26f05cda027ff58d47b7e4e5-b8262dcddcbefce4-00",
  "errors": {
    "Partner": [
      "The A field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

When I add the `A` object to the request like this:

```
{
  "aId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "A": {}
}
```

It creates a new record in both tables `A` and `B` (and I obviously don't want to allow this in the first place).

My expected outcome it to create a new record in `B` using the first request sample and not having to send the `A` object in the request at all, and especially not to have `B` inserting new records into `A`.

This is the first time I'm getting this error and it is a very strange one. What am I missing here?

Comment: How have you defined your controller action and the viewmodel it takes as input? It seems like you have a viewmodel with a required `A` property. This part of the problem is unrelated to EF Core.

Comment: The controller has a simple `[HttpPost]` action that receives an object of type `B`. Here is how: `[HttpPost] public IActionResult Create(B entity) {}`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add that information. Also is the input type `B` the same as the database entity type? Otherwise, please include the definition of `B` in the question as well. I would recommend adding a DTO instead of using the database type directly in your controller actions.